# Invalid HTTP Host: Kafka ElasticSearch Sink Connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use elasticsearch as a db for my application by using kafka connect in between. KafkaConnect,  elasticsearch(version 7) and my application are running in a containers in a same network. When I trie to access elasticsearch from the container for kafkaconnect, it is successful. But my  connector keeps throwing me the following error and I can't seem to figure out the exact issue:

Error:

```
container_standalone    | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid HTTP host: elasticsearch:9200/
container_standalone    |   at org.apache.http.HttpHost.create(HttpHost.java:123)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.lambda$getClientConfig$0(JestElasticsearchClient.java:201)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.getClientConfig(JestElasticsearchClient.java:201)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:149)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.<init>(JestElasticsearchClient.java:142)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:122)
container_standalone    |   at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:51)
container_standalone    |   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:300)
container_standalone    |   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
container_standalone    |   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
container_standalone    |   at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
container_standalone    |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
container_standalone    |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
container_standalone    | [2020-09-23 09:47:09,366] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
```

Configuration File:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=vehicle
topic.index=test-vehicle
connection.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
connection.username=username
connection.password=password
type.name=log
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Elastic.yml file:

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
```

Comment: Are you able to `ping elasticsearch`? Appears to be a DNS error, not Kafka connect. Can you show your Docker commands?

Comment: I have tried to run `docker exec container_standalone curl -sS http://elasticsearch:9200/` and it gives me the expected right result, when I try connect to elastic-search.